Question about [void] and best way/practice to return an array from a function
So I tried to create a function that will look for my external drives by FriendlyName and if drive is plugged in to my PC I add it to the array list as a PATH with drive letter ("X:") so I can use it later for copying as a destination path. If external drive is not available then it will not be added. So If I have 3 ssds pluged I will have array with 3 paths returned, if only 2.. only 2 paths, 1 only 1.
I just wanted to try more dynamic way of detecting my external drives then hard codding it since sometimes assigned drive letter might change but FriendlyName will be the same for my ssds.
#That's how I used to have it
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$DestSSD = @(
    "X:\" #SSD-1
    "T:\" #SSD-2
    "A:\"  #SSD-3
)

I found online a simple template of function that returns an array and I modified it with my code. Everything works but I have some question.

What purpose does "void" and ", $target" serve in my code?

The function doesn't quite operate as expected without it for example if I replace , with return $target. I'm trying to better understand it. My function works but if there's a better way/logic to do what I'm trying to do please point it out since i appreciate it greatly learning different methods. Thanks for you help!
function GetSSDsPath {
    [OutputType([System.Collections.ArrayList])]
    Param(
        [array]$SSDList,
        [System.Collections.ArrayList]
        $Target = @()
    )
    foreach ($ssdName in $SSDList) {
        $SSD = Get-PSDrive | Where-Object {$_.Description -eq $ssdName}
        if($SSD){
            [void]$Target.Add("$($SSD):\") #example "X:\"
        }else{
            Write-Host "$($ssdName) not found"
        }
    }
    ,$Target
}

$ssdList = "SSD-1", "SSD-2", "SSD-3"
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$DestSSD = GetSSDsPath $ssdList


you have 3 questions in 1. that shouldn't be the case. your question needs focus on a specific topic.

@SantiagoSquarzon Sorry, Let me try to rephrase it and be more precise.


[void] -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/65906791/3156906, https://stackoverflow.com/a/55665963/3156906, * , $target creates a "sacrificial array" to return the [System.ArrayList] verbatim without powershell "unrolling" it -  https://stackoverflow.com/a/28724692/3156906, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28702588/in-what-conditions-does-powershell-unroll-items-in-the-pipeline, * return types - unnecessary, but adds readability if you can be bothered.


@mclayton this is why im trying to get this question focused, all 3 questions have been previously answered ;)

@mclayton Thanks for the links, I will check them out. So in general, implementation of [void] and , $target in my case is correct? Since I never used it I wasn't sure if that's the correct approach

there are some bugs around [void], preferable method is $null =. in this case, you don't need either if you use a List<T> instead of ArrayList. Returning the collection without enumeration (by using ,) is also not the correct approach as you're killing the good qualities of a PowerShell function such as streaming output

@SantiagoSquarzon thanks, I will try to run it with Generic.List and look into $null method for the future. I will also look into enumeration.
