# Testing for null in Powershell: Why does testing an empty array behave differently from an empty string?

Tags: arrays, powershell, types, null

Consider this code

```
"Type: array"
$v = @()
"  -eq `$null: $($v -eq $null)"
"  -ne `$null: $($v -ne $null)"

"Type: string"
$v = ''
"  -eq `$null: $($v -eq $null)"
"  -ne `$null: $($v -ne $null)"
```

which produces the following result:

```
Type: array
  -eq $null: 
  -ne $null: 
Type: string
  -eq $null: False
  -ne $null: True
```

1. Why does `-eq` and `-ne` behave as expected for an empty string, but evaluate to null or empty for an empty array?
2. More importantly, how do you distinguish between `$null` and an empty array?

Answer (score 6):

When comparison operators are used against a collection, they do not return a boolean value ($true or $false).  They return all the members of the collection that meet the condition.

See:

Get-help [About_Comparison_Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx)

Comment: Oh.  That makes a bit more sense.  But then why doesn't `@() -eq $null` evaluate to true?

Comment: @alx9r That answer might be dependent on your PowerShell version. In 3.0 that evaluates to False for me.

Comment: @() -eq $null will return all the members of the empty array that are equal to $null, so the result will be null, not $true. Note that $() -eq $null does return $true. $() evaluates to a scalar (single) null.

Comment: @mjolinor Can you tell me (or link to) what the meaning of `$()` is?  Neither google nor stackoverflow search turns anything up for that character string.

Comment: That's a subexpression.  See get-help about_Operators.

Answer (score 2):

@mjolinor's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29614241/1404637) is a simple and correct answer to question (1).  That answer actually leads to two more questions.

[about_Comparison_Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx) states the following:

> When the input is a collection of values, the 
>   comparison operators return any matching values. If there are no matches
>   in a collection, comparison operators do not return anything.

This implies the behavior depends on Powershell's definition of "collection" in this context.  [Pipeline unrolling has a similar dependence on the definition of "collection".](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28707054/1404637)  It also implies that swapping the LHS and RHS of comparison operators might make a material difference.

So in addition to the original question 2, we have two more unanswered questions:

2. How do you distinguish between `$null` and an empty array?
3. What types does Powershell comparison operators treat as a collection?
4. Does swapping the LHS and RHS of the comparison operators make a difference?

These three remaining questions can all be answered empirically using the script at the end of this answer.

### Test Results

```
CollectionType x_eq_Null coll_LHS_result Null_eq_x coll_RHS_result
-------------- --------- --------------- --------- ---------------
string             False Boolean             False Boolean        
ArrayList             {} Object[]            False Boolean        
Hashtable          False Boolean             False Boolean        
Queue                 {} Object[]            False Boolean        
SortedList         False Boolean             False Boolean        
Stack                 {} Object[]            False Boolean        
Dictionary         False Boolean             False Boolean        
List                  {} Object[]            False Boolean        
Null                True Boolean              True Boolean        
boolean            False Boolean             False Boolean        
int32              False Boolean             False Boolean        
char               False Boolean             False Boolean
```

We can use the table to answer the questions:

> 2. How do you distinguish between `$null` and an empty array?

Moving the collection to the RHS of the operator (e.g. `$null -eq @()`) yields a Boolean for all types tested (see column `coll_RHS_result`).  This means that `$null -ne @()` evaluates to True as expected which allows us to reliably detect the difference between `$null` and `@()`.

> 3. What types does Powershell comparison operators treat as a collection?

Each of the types whose `coll_LHS_result` is `Object[]`.

> 4. Does swapping the LHS and RHS of the comparison operators make a difference?

It sure does.  Putting a collection on the LHS of the operator yields an array as a result.  Putting a scalar on the LHS of the operator yields a boolean as a result.

### The Test Script

```
('string',     ('')),
('ArrayList',  (New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList)),
('Hashtable',  (New-Object System.Collections.Hashtable)),
('Queue',      (New-Object System.Collections.Queue)),
('SortedList', (New-Object System.Collections.SortedList)),
('Stack',      (New-Object System.Collections.Stack)),
('Dictionary', (New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary``2[System.String,int32]")),
('List',       (New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List``1[int32])),
('Null',       ($null)),
('boolean',    ($false)),
('int32',      ([int32]0)),
('char',       ([char]"`0")) |
    % {
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{ 
            CollectionType   =  $_[0]
            x_eq_Null        =  $_[1] -eq $null
            coll_LHS_result  = ($_[1] -eq $null).GetType().Name
            Null_eq_x        =  $null -eq $_[1]
            coll_RHS_result  = ($null -eq $_[1]).GetType().Name
        }
    } |
    select CollectionType,x_eq_Null,coll_LHS_result,Null_eq_x,coll_RHS_result |
    ft -AutoSize
```

Comment: And another interesting related question - how are objects in general, and collections specifically, converted/cast to boolean (true/false) values for evaluation of statements such as `if ($x)`? The answer lies in `System.Management.Automation.LanguagePrimitives.IsTrue` : http://blog.whatsupduck.net/2012/01/casting-objects-to-boolean-in.html