# .count in multiple powershell versions

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a portion of a powershell script  that checks locations and verifies the count of files, then runs checks based on the count. The powershell script is ran on multiple machines, one of which is running powershell 2.0.

I'm using something like:

```
$folder = Get-Item "Parent Folder"
$files  = (Get-ChildItem $folder.Fullname)
```

When I check `$files.Count` it will be accurate in versions of powershell greater than 2.0.
In Powershell 2.0, `files.Count` will not return anything if `$files` only contains 1 file. If there is more than  1  file, then it returns the correct number count (non-null).

I'm assuming this has to do with `$files` not being an array if Get-ChildItem only returns one value.

I know that checking the powershell version and modifying the script per version would resolve this issue, but I'd prefer to avoid it.

**Is there some other way to check the count uniformly across multiple versions of powershell?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a known gotcha, you have to cast return value to array for PS 2.0. It was fixed in PS 3.0:

> You can now use Count or Length on any object, even if it didn’t have
>   the property.  If the object didn’t have a Count or Length property,
>   it will will return 1 (or 0 for $null).  Objects that have Count or
>   Length properties will continue to work as they always have.

Example:

```
$files = @(Get-ChildItem $folder.Fullname)
```

or

```
[array]$files = Get-ChildItem $folder.Fullname
```

References:

- [New V3 Language Features](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2012/06/14/new-v3-language-features.aspx)
- [How does the Count property work in Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26504589/how-does-the-count-property-work-in-powershell)

Comment: IMHO, does not use cast to `[array]`. It does not return empty array in case of empty pipeline. And if pipeline return single element and that single element is collection, then cast to `[array]` will copy elements of collection to array instead of wrapping collection in single element array, as `@()` does.

Comment: @PetSerAl Agreed, thanks for clarifying. `[array]` behavior sometimes is more preferable, because in case of empty return value it will contain `$null` which can be easily compared using comparison operators. It's not so straightforward with empty arrays, because when being used  against an array, [comparison operators do not return a boolean value ($true or $false). They return all the members of the array that meet the condition.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29614241/4424236)

Comment: In case of empty array, you can just compare `$array.Count -eq 0` or `-not $array.Count`.