# Why can't I return a value of type System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection?

Tags: .net, function, powershell, return-type, powershell-4.0

I can create a new instance of the `[System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection]` type, and it seems to work fine. But if I do it inside a function, and then return the object, the caller receives either a `[String]` (if the collection contains only a single item) or `[Object[]]` if it contains multiple items (and then each item in that array is a `[String]` representing one of the keys).

This can be reproduced with the following code:

```psh
function Test-ReturnType {
[CmdletBinding()]
param()

    $nvc = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection
    Write-Verbose $nvc.GetType() -Verbose
    $nvc.Add('Name1','Value1')
    $nvc.Add('Name2','Value2')
    $nvc
}

$r = Test-ReturnType

Write-Verbose $r.GetType() -Verbose
```

I've confirmed that the `.Add()` method has a `[void]` return type, and piping to `Out-Null` doesn't change the behavior.

I've tried to add an `[OutputType()]` attribute to the function even though I know that's for documentation only.

I've tried casting `$nvc` in the last line of the function (no effect).

I've tried casting `$r` and the return value of `Test-ReturnType` (exception, can't convert).

I just don't understand why this isn't possible.

If I create a new `[System.Net.WebClient]` for example and return that from the function, it works just fine.

Why does `[System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection]` get turned into its stored values upon return?

Comment: @Kev I agree actually; I'll VTC too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Powershell is being "helpful" here and unwrapping your collection for you the same way it unwraps arrays/etc. as they enter the pipeline.

You need to "prevent" that by adding a layer of array/wrapping for powershell to unwrap instead.

Try `,$nvc` as the last line instead.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28702588/258523) for some discussion about powershell unrolling.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you. aaand the link you just edited in answered my remaining question (which types does powershell do this for). I also figured out another workaround which is far more convoluted. I'm going to post it as answer but I'll accept yours once the time has passed.

Comment: For as much as that question has an answer at least. It ended up with "some things but we don't really know why" as far as I recall.

Comment: Yeah, it's disappointing that there isn't a canonical list or set of rules for it, but knowing that is itself useful.

Answer (score 1):

I found another workaround. Return a reference to the object:

```psh
[ref]$nvc
```

Only thing is, the caller has to dereference it before using it:

```psh
$r = Test-ReturnType
$r.value.GetType()
```

So definitely not as good as the unary `,` but still something interesting.