# Why do certain data types get changed by this code construct?

Tags: powershell, ternary-operator

Sometime ago I found that this construct seemed to work nicely in lieu of a native ternary conditional operator in PowerShell:

```
$result = if ( $myBoolExpression ) { 'a' } else { 'b' }
```

But I recently found that its correctness is datatype-dependent: for certain data types, it will modify the data type it returns!

If you run the following test code, you will see that it works fine for strings: $t1 is 'a' and it is, in fact, a string.
And it works fine for DateTime objects ($t2). But it fails for DataTable objects ($t3 and $t4). It seems to slice off the outermost container and return the next layer, after a fashion. With $t3, the operands are empty data tables so $t3 is getting a $null. With $t4, the operands are data tables populated with datarows, but $t4 is an object array containing datarows. Both $t3 and $t4 should have been DataTables, I would have thought.

**Question 1:** why does this construct morph certain data types but not others?

**Question 2:** why is the last line in GetDataTable() required?
By which, I mean, if it was instead a simple "return $dataTable" instead of "return @(,($dataTable ))" then it *also* returns an object array instead of a DataTable! So perhaps this is another symptom of the same issue...?

*(Note that I am aware there are other ways to emulate ternary behavior--notably [Ternary operator in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31341998/115690)--but I don't like leaving unexplained issues around :-)*

```
function DoTest {

    $t1 = if ( $true) { 'a' } else { 'b' }
    $t1.GetType().Name # prints 'String'

    $obj1 = New-Object DateTime
    $obj2 = New-Object DateTime
    $t2 = if ( $true) { $obj1 } else { $obj2 }
    $t2.GetType().Name # prints 'DateTime'

    $obj1 = New-Object Data.DataTable
    $obj2 = New-Object Data.DataTable
    $t3 = if ( $true) { $obj1 } else { $obj2 }
    $t3 -eq $null # prints $true!
    # $t3.GetType().Name

    $obj1 = GetDataTable
    "obj1 is " + $obj1.GetType().Name
    $obj2 = GetDataTable
    $t4 = if ( $true) { $obj1 } else { $obj2 } # Question 1
    $t4.GetType().Name # prints 'Object[]'
    $t4[0].GetType().Name # prints 'DataRow'
}

DoTest
```

The supplement GetDataTable function is shown here. It is only used as a convenience function to create a non-empty DataTable:

```
function GetDataTable {
    $dataTable = New-Object Data.DataTable
    $Col = New-Object Data.DataColumn
    $Col.ColumnName = 'stuff'
    $dataTable.Columns.Add($Col )
    $row = $dataTable.NewRow()
    $row['stuff' ] = 'abc'
    $dataTable.Rows.Add($row )
    $row = $dataTable.NewRow()
    $row['stuff' ] = 'xyz'
    $dataTable.Rows.Add($row )
    return @(,($dataTable )) # Question 2-- just "return $dataTable" is insufficient
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The unrolling of the array type is something powershell does a lot and [it can really bite you at the worst of times](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32118702/3905079).

I suspect the interpretation to `$null` is a similar part of [PowerShell's Extended Type System](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/besidethepoint/archive/2011/11/22/psobject-and-the-adapted-and-extended-type-systems-ats-and-ets.aspx).

It's can get convoluted at times, unfortunately.