# PowerShell cmdlet is changing the type of the returned object

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-cmdlet

This behavior is mystifying!

Consider the following PowerShell script:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("Newtonsoft.Json.dll") | Out-Null

function ConvertFrom-JsonNet {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string] $Json
    )

    $O = [Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject]::Parse($Json)
    Write-Host $O.GetType().Name

    return $O
}

Clear-Host

$Json = '{"test":"prop"}'
$O1 = ConvertFrom-JsonNet '{"test":"prop"}'
$O2 = [Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject]::Parse($Json)

Write-Host $O1.GetType().Name
Write-Host $O2.GetType().Name
```

You'd expect the output to be:

```
JObject
JObject
JObject
```

but it's not! It's:

```
JObject
JProperty
JObject
```

How is this possible? How is the type of the object *within* the function `JObject`, but then after it's passed out of the function, it's `JProperty`?

Comment: `JObject` implements several interfaces; one of them is `IEnumerable`. Is PowerShell detecting that it implements `IEnumerable` and expanding the object when it puts it on the pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

*Sigh*

Yay for PowerShell's inflexibility!

Apparently, PowerShell will "unroll" all collections that are destined for the pipeline. In this case, `JObject` implements `ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, JToken>>`. The `JObject`'s collection contains a single `JProperty`, which is what was being "unrolled" into the pipeline. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695474/powershell-converts-values-returned-from-function-how-to-avoid-this) answer, which shows that rolling a collection into an outer collection will cause the intended value to be placed in the pipeline.

Wouldn't it be nice if PowerShell had a mechanism for adding something to the pipeline untouched? :)